# Почему этот код генерации картинки очень сильно нагружает сервер?

Tags: php, оптимизация, изображения

Почему этот код генерации картинки очень сильно нагружает сервер?:

```
<?php
$str=file_get_contents('http://example.com/');
$str=strstr($str, 'MAIN Force-Zone SERVER');
preg_match('/Игроки:\s\<[\D]{40}\>\s\d{1,}\s\/\s\d{1,}/', $str, $cplayers);
preg_match('/\d{1,}\s\/\s\d{1,}/', $cplayers[0], $cplayers);
preg_match('/\d{1,}/', $cplayers[0], $ncpp);
$cplayers=$cplayers[0];
$ncpp=$ncpp[0];
$pl=array(' empty slot', ' empty', ' empty slot', ' empty slot', ' empty slot');
$plk=array(' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A');
$plp=array(' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A', ' N/A');
preg_match('/\s{6}\<tr\/\>\n\s{8}/', $str, $nts);
preg_match_all("#<tr style='background-color:[^>]+'><td>([^<]+)</td><td>([^<]+)</td><td>([^<]+)</td>#is", $str, $pplayers);
//Основные настройки
header('Content-type: image/png');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$im=@ImageCreateFromPNG('./bg.png');
$color=array(imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125),
             imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125),
             imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125),
             imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125),
             imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125),
             imagecolorallocate($im, 125, 125, 125));
$font='./times.ttf';
//Сортировка по массивам
for ($i=0; $i<$ncpp; $i++) {
    $pl[$i]=$pplayers[1][$i];
    $plk[$i]=$pplayers[2][$i];
    $plp[$i]=$pplayers[3][$i];
    $color[$i]=imagecolorallocate($im, 146, 201, 199);
}
//Ники игроков
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 33, 184, $color[0], $font, $pl[0]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 33, 201, $color[1], $font, $pl[1]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 33, 219, $color[2], $font, $pl[2]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 33, 235, $color[3], $font, $pl[3]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 33, 255, $color[4], $font, $pl[4]);
//Фраги игроков
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 221, 184, $color[0], $font, $plk[0]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 221, 201, $color[1], $font, $plk[1]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 221, 219, $color[2], $font, $plk[2]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 221, 235, $color[3], $font, $plk[3]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 221, 255, $color[4], $font, $plk[4]);
//Пинг игроков
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 260, 184, $color[0], $font, $plp[0]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 260, 201, $color[1], $font, $plp[1]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 260, 219, $color[2], $font, $plp[2]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 260, 235, $color[3], $font, $plp[3]);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 260, 255, $color[4], $font, $plp[4]);
//Сколько из скольки
imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 170, 133, $color[0], $font, $cplayers);
//Вывод изображения
imagepng($im, NULL);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Генерация картинки - сам по себе процесс ресурсоёмкий. А тут еще куча регулярных выражений.

Comment: Хех. Я хотел статистику игрового сервера, методом парсинга, выводить на красивый фон и потом разместить у себя в подписи на форуме. Но так как форум посещаемый, то и мой хост забанили за то, он вызывал гигантскую нагрузку на сервер. По другому сделать не получилось, так как только в этом всём разбираюсь :(

Comment: Значит есть смысл картинки генерировать и сохранять, а обновлять, например, раз в сутки.

Comment: На так же не интересно — люди заходят и выходят с сервера каждую минуту => картинка должна быть каждый раз новая :(

Comment: Тогда не надо экономить на сервере....)

Comment: @ImirofF, только ради этого серв покупать не буду я :)
@Sh4dow, хах! А это идея! Спасибо!:)

Comment: так в итоге ЧТО выходит? заинтересовал скрипт. цветные квадратики что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Никита Рабыкин](/users/5000/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD), кэшируйте ее хотя бы на 5 минут. Нагрузка уменьшится во много раз. А вниз допишите что-то вроде "обновлено в XX ч XX мин"